# std::tie for less comparison and char arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, comparison, std

I've always known that to implement in a fast way a operator< for a class, the fastest way that always works is to use std::tie.

E.g.

```
struct TestInt
{
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
};

TestInt first;
TestInt second(first);

bool aLess = std::tie( first.a, first.b)
  < std::tie(second.a, second.b);
bool bLess = std::tie( first.a, first.b)
  > std::tie(second.a, second.b);
EXPECT_EQ(aLess, false);
EXPECT_EQ(bLess, false);
EXPECT_EQ(aLess, bLess);
```

The same does not work if you use another struct containing members with array of chars
like:

```
struct TieTestChar
  {
  char a[10];
  int b=0;
  TieTestChar() {strcpy(a, "test");}
  };

TieTestChar first;
TieTestChar second(first);

bool aLess = std::tie( first.a, first.b)
  < std::tie(second.a, second.b);
bool bLess = std::tie( first.a, first.b)
  > std::tie(second.a, second.b);
EXPECT_EQ(aLess, false);
EXPECT_EQ(bLess, false);
EXPECT_EQ(aLess, bLess);
```

What am I missing?

[test case edited]

Comment: I think that's because you're trying to compare addresses of `char[]`

Comment: that makes sense

Comment: use `strncmp` or `strncasecmp` to compare `char[]`

Comment: I was looking for a generic way to compare structures. std::tie used to work for my previous tests, but not in this case

Comment: instead of `char[]` use `std::string`

Comment: can't use std::string in that specific case @Harry

Comment: Use `std::string` or `std::array`, which will allow you to use `std::tie` or provide your own `operator==` for your class.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions but as I said I can't use them as I can't touch that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might mimic `std::tie` with special case for C-arrays, something along

```
template <typename T>
struct my_ref
{
    using type = T&;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct my_ref<T[N]>
{
    using type = my_span<T/*, N*/>; // std::span doesn't provide comparison operators
};

template <typename T>
using my_ref_t = typename my_ref<T>::type;

template <typename ... Ts>
std::tuple<my_ref_t<Ts>...> my_tie(const Ts&... args) { return {args...}; }
```

Comment: interesting solution. So you're suggestion I create a kind of std::span with comparison operations? is there a simpler solution too in your opinion?

Comment: I expected comparison function for `std::span`, so provided answer would be fine and simple. When I checked it was not the case, creating your own `span` seems the way to go (`span` is not complicated to implement).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I hoped for a quicker alternative, but I'll try to find more details about span